# What should my button read, when user is done reading a text / message

Tags: text

I have a pop up which has a text / message / announcement to read by user.

[image: Mockup]

When user is done reading, I would want user to close pop up window by clicking button below this message or text.

Can you guys suggest text , this button should have ?

Comment: Without knowing the context and the content of the message, it is impossible to give advice on this.

Comment: I have added a mockup I created. Can you suggest now

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve by this widget (popup?) at all. Don't think labeling a button will have an impact on the user actually reading the text, not even if you label the button that way. Users will just want to dismiss the disturbance as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, I'm not sure of a time when that text would be best served up as an overlay. Consider implementing the copy into the website itself and saving yourself the trouble.

Comment: Sorry, I should have read this before posting my own answer. I totally agree. +1.

Answer (score 3):

"Mark as read" (as in email). Although I don't find it user friendly if you are leaving no choice. Read it or else! Read it now! You're forcing a declaration from your user. Either it should only say "Close", or offer an alternative, say, "Mark as read" as checkbox - could be checked by default - and a "Close" button next to it. Or perhaps "Mark as read" / "Read it later".

Comment: +1 an adequate answer to an otherwise inadequate question.

Comment: In addition to this I think it depends whether it is a broadcast message or something sent specifically to that person. In the former I think of something similar that what the banks do with a close/hide button and a checkbox saying "don't show me this again" defaulting to unchecked. If it is something sent specifically to that person then I agree it should be something like "mark as read" and "read later"

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: **a simple "Close" or "OK" will do the job**. Clicking such a button implies that you have read the message. Do not add that inside the button's label.

But... Looking at the mockup I am wondering whether such information should go inside such a message window. Should you not put such information permanently somewhere so that the user can get the information at the time he needs it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the tone of voice currently used in the system, IMO. I like to use more informal language as it adds a level of familiarity between the user and the system and it also means you can make sentences that are much more accurate! By that account I think I'd go with "Yep, I've read this" or "Read and understood, thanks!"

As far as context goes I'm assuming it's [the popup] housing a message that the user is required to confirm because of some business logic? If that's the case I agree with you that a lighbox or popup is better than having the message in the page. Obbiously with a lightbox one should always consider that it can easily be worked around.

If the context assumed above is incorrect (which it probably is judging by content in example) have you considered a lightbox with perma-position. I.e. the element appears as a lightbox but pre-positioned to where it will stay on the page. The user clicks the close/ok button and the lightbox layer fades revealing the website with the message staying put on the screen where it was. Assuming HTML/CSS interface this is easily achieved by having the Z index of the message higher than a lightbox layer and the lightbox layer higher than the main content